# Expected peak to trough calculation

Tags: r, probability

I am having trouble coding up in R equation 3.1 in the following paper: http://www.intelligenthedgefundinvesting.com/pubs/rb-cb.pdf

My function:

```
expected.drawdown<-function(mn,sd,t){
  ret<-mn - ((sd^2)/2) #return R

  a<- (ret * sqrt(t))/sd
  b<- (ret * t) + (((sd^2) * t)/2)
  c<- -(sqrt(t) * (ret + (sd^2))) / sd

  x<-(2*ret*pnorm(a)) + (2 * exp(b) * (ret * (sd^2)) * pnorm(c))

  x<-x/((2*ret)+ (sd^2))

  exp.dd<- 1 - x

  return(exp.dd)
}
```

In page four with the graph, I tried plugging in the values

```
sd<-0.3162 #/sqrt(252)
mu<-(sd^2) * 0.5
t<-60 #years
expected.drawdown(mu,sd,t)
> 1
```

while the graph approximates to 0.73 at year 60. Anyone has any idea where I am making mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error is in the following line:

```
x<-(2*ret*pnorm(a)) + (2 * exp(b) * (ret * (sd^2)) * pnorm(c))
```

Change the multiplication `(ret * (sd^2))` to an addition `(ret + (sd^2))` and you're doing fine: the function returns the value $0.713$ which matches the value of the function in the graph on page 4.